# Gtk::Widget missing set_visual() method in gtkmm-3.0

Tags: c, c++11, gtk3, gtkmm

As seen in the Gtk documentation [here](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Widget.set_visual.html) there is a method to set the visual of the Widget which seems to be missing from gtkmm (C++ wrapper).

While trying to port a Gtk application from C to C++ using gtkmm-3.0, quickly discovered that the set_visual() method is missing. Although there is a [get_visual()](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.0/classGtk_1_1Widget.html) that returns the visual of the widget.

The C code looks like this:

```
  GdkScreen *screen = gtk_widget_get_screen(widget);
  GdkVisual *visual = gdk_screen_get_rgba_visual(screen);
  if (visual == NULL)
    visual = gdk_screen_get_system_visual(screen);

  gtk_widget_set_visual(widget, visual);
```

Does anyone know how can i set the widget visual with a custom one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the C++ wrapper does not provide what you need, you can always get a pointer to the underlying C `GObject` instance and work with it as you would in a typical GTK C application. Check out [this method](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.24/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a6667a82920375b2ebde07bc1ffdc3641) for `Gtk::Widget`:

```cpp
GtkWidget* Gtk::Widget::gobj()
```

So you can call this on your widget, get a C `GtkWidget` pointer and call `gtk_widget_set_visual` on it like you are doing in your question. Note that this solution works all across Gtkmm, which in my opinion is a really nice feature that other wrappers do not have.